# Как удалить событие из другой функции?

Tags: javascript, события

Есть див у которого увеличивается ширина за счет события onmousemove:

```
let div1 = document.querySelector('#div1');
let width1 = 100;
div1.onmousemove = f1;

function f1(event) {
    div1.style.width = width1 + 'px';
    width1++;
    return event;
}
```

Хочу добавить кнопку toggle, которая будет контролировать это событие. Нажал - функция f15 не работает = див не увеличивается, нажал еще раз - функция f15 снова работает. Но не понимаю, как это реализовать. Попытался сделать внутри f1 return event и вызвать этот ивент в функции fToggle, но консоль выводила undefined.

```
btnToggle.onclick = fToggle;

function fToggle() {
    console.log(f1()); /// undefined
    
}
```

Знаю что существует способ, removeEventListener, то здесь addEventListenera нет.

P.S. Возможно у меня изначально логика неверна и не нужно ничего усложнять и сделать через if/else, но мне хотелось взаимодействовать именно через изменение event'а. Сделал пока такой костыль:

```
function fToggle() {
    if (div1.onmousemove == f1) {
        div1.onmousemove = false;
    }
    else {
        div1.onmousemove = f1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Возможно не нужно ничего усложнять и сделать через if/else

Да)

```js
let width = 100;
let div = document.querySelector('#div');

div.onmousemove = f;

function f() {
  div.style.width = ++width + 'px';
}

document.querySelector('#btn').onclick = function() {
  div.onmousemove = div.onmousemove ? null : f;
};
```

```css
#div { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: orange }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Toggle</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```

В `div.onmousemove` присваивается результат выражения `div.onmousemove ? null : f`. Если div.onmousemove уже ссылается на какую-то функцию, она в логическом контексте будет true — возьмется null. Если уже null (false) — тогда функция `f`

---

Но не всегда удобно / нужно так переключать функции. Можно завести внешнюю переменную, от которой зависит выполнение функции:

```js
let width = 100, dont_grow = false;

document.querySelector('#div').addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
  if (dont_grow) return; // Если dont_grow — true, прервать выполнение.
  div.style.width = ++width + 'px';
});

document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  dont_grow = !dont_grow;
});
```

```css
#div { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: orange }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Toggle</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```

`a = !b`, оператор `!` сперва приводит значение `b` к логическому типу, а затем возвращает противоположное значение. В примере выше у `dont_grow` и так логический тип, получается постоянное переключение между `true ←→ false`

P.s. Чтобы постоянно не задумываться, а будет ли у элемента один обработчик или несколько (`onсобытия` одновременно могут ссылаться только на одну функцию), было бы удобно везде использовать addEventListener и не париться )

Comment: Спасибо за столько развернутый ответ!